# :-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'MyProject.obj'

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I use Qt Creator 4.10.0 in windows 7.

The name of my project is MyProject.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-12-23T11:43:59
#
#-------------------------------------------------
QT       += core gui
QT       += serialport
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = MDT
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
checkboxheader.cpp \
ft_file_info.cpp \
ui_dll_function.cpp \
ui_utility.cpp \
startprocess.cpp \
qmdttimer.cpp \
usbswitch.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
checkboxheader.h \
ft_file_info.h \
ui_dll_function.h \
ui_utility.h \
startprocess.h \
qmdttimer.h \
QMtrace.h \
usbswitch.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
INCLUDEPATH += ./DownloadLib
LIBS += -LD:\EPS_projects\2018to2019\29_IOT_MDI\IoT_MDT_official\lib - 
lDownloadLib \
 QMTRACE.lib \ 
 EfuseLibrary.lib \
 D:\MyProject \ boost_1_71_0\libs \ 
RESOURCES += \
icons.qrc
#LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lQMTRACE   / -lEfuseLibrary
#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lEfuseLibrary
#win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lEfuseLibrary
#win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lusb_relay_device
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/DownloadLib
```

when I build the project, error occurs: cannot open file 'MyProject.obj'

Build steps:
qmake: qmake.exe MDT.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug"  "CONFIG+=qml_debug"

There is no MyProject.obj in my folder.

Comment: Does `MyProject.obj` exist? Did you get any compile errors?  It will be difficult to help with so little information.

Comment: There is no MyProject.obj in the folder.

Comment: Were there any build errors before this link error? If not you may want to remove the code from the question and replace it with the pro file. Since the bug is likely in the pro file.

Comment: I put the .pro file on

Comment: This is most likely caused by the strange spaces of the last entry in LIBS: D:\MyProject \ boost_1_71_0\libs

Comment: I was not sure that was a copy paste error or the actual file contents.

Answer (score 1):

You have this line here

```
 D:\MyProject \
```

Backslash separated by space "`\`" is a line wrapper in QMake file format, anything after it is ignored.

Because of such mistakes, as well because of code portability requirements,  Qt supports slash character `/` as divider for Windows paths. Using absolute paths in .pro file is also unwise.